# Print from python to dot-matrix printer

Tags: python, printing, printer-control-language, parallel-port, dot-matrix

I need to print to a dot-matrix printer, with continuous-sheet paper.

My program is written in Python 2.7 and runs in Windows.

The printer is connected to a parallel port.

I need to print text, not images, however I need to set font family and size, and the exact size of the paper.

I absolutely **don't want to use win32api and/or the Windows driver**, because it has a number of issues (main one, it cannot correctly set the paper height).

I guess I should send some escape sequence directly to the printer. How should I do?

If it can be useful, this is the exact printer model:
EPSON LX-300+ /II
https://www.epson.it/products/printers/dot-matrix-printers/epson-lx-300ii

Comment: I don't think it's trivial to send data directly to the printer; font rendering engines are not really simple.

Comment: Ok, I may relax the requirement "I need to set font family and size". I could use default printer fonts.

Comment: did you find out how to do it?

Comment: Well, yes, however the result is not beautiful. At last, I have used win32print module, I send directly escape characters to printer using WritePrinter()